# How to move an Xcode 4.5 project, complete with GIT snapshots, to a new location

Tags: git, xcode4.5

I'm moving an Xcode 4.5 project to a different computer.  The project has quite a few snapshots.  I'd like all my snapshots to travel with the project to the new computer and be visible in "Restore snapshot" under the Xcode File menu.

I understand .git has a hardcoded path in the project.  How can I set things up in the new location so the project can find its transferred git repository?

Answer (score 0):

Push your repository up to Github or Bitbucket (or any git server location) and then pull it down to the new computer.  That will have everything not outlined in .gitignore.  The path to the git repository won't matter.  The structure within your project will be preserved since your last commit, so that should have everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

`git push` + `git pull` ^.^

Sent it to a remote server, and then retrieve it on the new computer. This is pretty much what GIT is for, in addition to version control.

If you run any sort of server for a website, you can setup your own GIT server, or you can register for an account of GitHub. This will allow you to have off-site backups, and you will be able to download your code, with full history, for anywhere you wish to work.